# How to avoid backslash in java

Tags: java

First look at the code below

```
public static void main(String args[])
   {
     System.out.println(new Stringtest().test("The system has saved your payment under        transaction number \369825655."));
    }

private String test(String aa)
    {
        return aa.substring(58);
    }
```

so logically this method should print 369825665. But it is printing 9825655 because of that backslash. Now I want the whole number. What should I do. I can not change the \ to \\ because the text is coming from a website.

Comment: Cause naturally, all website text is immutable and uncopyable.

Comment: I would avoid adding or use backslashes. There are lots of other symbols you can use like `transaction number: 369825655`

Comment: BTW, in *my* mind, this "logically" shouldn't even compile.  But since Java unfortunately understands octal escape sequences, `\36` turns into character 30 (the ASCII "record separator" char).

Comment: You're getting source code from the web site that you then compile?? Can't you read in the string from the web site yourself in code, which would give you a string in the intended format without having to worry about escaping and unescaping?

Comment: You are going to have to explain this 'text is coming from a website' business. It is meaningless to me.

Comment: I am using selenium tool to automate the site. I'm making payment on the site using this tool and have to grab the transaction id after the payment. The selenium tool grabs this line of text from the site. And now i have to extract the transaction id from this line.

Comment: OK, but why do you extract the text from the line and put it in Java source code which you then compile? Why not just read it in from the page using the Selenium API? Then you wouldn't have to worry about the compiler's handling of backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\` is an escape character.  You need to escape the escape character.

```
System.out.println(new Stringtest().test("The system has saved your payment under transaction number \\369825655."));
```

For more on escape sequences, see [this Oracle document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).  Essentially the backslash tells the system that the character(s) after it should be interpreted in a special manner (not simply as plain text).  When you escape the escape, it gets treated specially as well... as plain text, instead of as an escape character.

It can get confusing sometimes but is intuitive once you learn the core concepts.

**EDIT:** If you can't control the format the String comes to you in, you might be out of luck.  I've been debugging this in Eclipse, and it seems like as soon as you create your String with that, the escape character gets processed and you lose the first two digits of your transaction number.  You may need to get your database guys (or whomever formatted this terrible String) to change their implementation for you to do what you need to do.  The Eclipse debugger suggests this, at least.

It just so happens that, apparently, `\36` processes fine and gets interpreted as another ASCII character that doesn't show up.  But in other cases, this will likely throw an Exception as an invalid escape sequence.

In my own testing, it seems that as soon as the String literal is declared/created, the loss of information occurs.  So there will be no way to recover it after that to my knowledge.

[Debug Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI6Qk.png)
[image: debug info]

Comment: No I can not change the text. It is coming from a website.

Comment: Then you will need to create a new String from the one you receive from the website if you intend to use the approach in your above approach.  You can't modify that String, because Strings are immutable.

Comment: But when i create a new string the text goes into the new string as "The system has saved your payment under transaction number 9825655". Meansa the first two digits of the number vanishes.

Comment: The Eclipse debugger confirms this.  See my edit.  You may need to get whoever gives you this to change their code, if it genuinely strips the digits out at the time of string creation.  Or maybe you could take it in as a character array and then do what you need to do.

Comment: Actually, even immediately converting it to a `char[]` doesn't save the data.  Literally as soon as the String literal is created you lose the information.

Comment: @KapilGarg The problem is that Strings are immutable.  As soon as you receive that String from the server, the information you want has *already been lost* as soon as that String was created in the system. There is no way to get it back.  Now, if you show us the code you're using to retrieve the String in the first place, maybe we could do some preprocessing to save it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `\\369825655` - basically it escapes the escape sign. Then replace all `\` characters with empty characters.

Comment: No I can not change the text. It is coming from a website.

Comment: Why don't you store it in a variable first, manipulate it, and then do whatever you need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Add another backslash (escape character)

```
ArrayList System.out.println(new Stringtest().test("The system has saved your payment under        transaction number \\369825655."));
```

Comment: No I can not change the text. It is coming from a website.

Comment: I think you can.  Just use the string replace function.

Comment: Yes, You just need to use String.replace() and replace \ with \\

Comment: private String test(String aa)
 {
  return aa.replace("\\", "\\\\");
 } thats wat u want to say but it is showing the result as The system has saved your payment under transaction number 9825655. means first two digits vanishes off